# SQLite doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I'm building a project using cordova/phonegap and the [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) plugin:

```
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "products.db",location: 'default'});
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (id integer primary key, product_id INTEGER,title text,price text, picture text,quantite INTEGER)');
    },errorc, function() {
            console.log('products table created');
        });
```

In the console I get "products table created" and everything works great, but when I try to insert anything:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO products (product_id, title, quantite, price, picture) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)',["1","1","1","1","1"]);
    },errorc,function() {
            $.magnificPopup.close();
            showMsg(msg_product_added);
            console.log('product added');
    });
```

... and then try to see if it's there and if there are any results with the field product_id equal 1 (the entry we added above does):

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql("SELECT count(product_id) as cnt FROM products WHERE product_id=?",1,function(tx,res){
            product_total = res.rows.item(0).cnt;
            if(product_total <= 0 ){
                alert("the row does not exists");
            }else{
                alert("the row exist");
            }
        })
    }, errorc);
```

I get "the row does not exists" every time. So what's wrong in the code? This is my error function that return the errors:

```
function errorc(error){
    console.log('error: ' + error.message)
}
```

Comment: Try to do the same thing in normal Web SQL in the browser (use window.openDatabase.instead of window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase) and more people can help you.

Comment: I suspect the TEXT type affinity is causing your issue. It is also possible to omit the type affinity, according to the online sqlite documentation.

Comment: @brodybits how should i declare the text type ?

Comment: Actually, you should probably rewrite the SELECT statement as follows: tx.executeSql("SELECT count(product_id) as cnt FROM products WHERE product_id=?",[1],

Comment: The SQL parameter(s) must always be in an array.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879785/cordova-sqlite-plugin-not-functioning-with-android-studio/33894275#33894275

Comment: Add an error capture to the "executeSql", not just the transaction and also be sure that the table really DOESN'T already exist. It might exist but not have the right columns for the INSERT to work.