# Change Loading Order in Cordova (Cordova SQLite Plugin)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

I have a Variable Reference Error in my Cordova iOS App.

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: db
```

The Variable is defined in the Plugin SQLite, but the SQLite Plugin is loading after my index.js. So it makes sense that it is not finding the Variable.
**But my Question is now:** 
*How can I change the loading order of the Plugin files or in general the loading order of the cordova files ?*
First I tried to change the config.xml, I added the 'onload' parameter:

```
<feature name="SQLitePlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="SQLitePlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

Then I tried to put my function where the Variable 'db' is used into a document.ready function, but then there was another reference error, because I called the function in my index.js before it was declared.

Comment: Please, show us some of the work you have done to resolve this issue.

Comment: I updated my Question @GoogleHireMe

Comment: You can also use `SQLite` without any plugin in `cordova`. Check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879785/cordova-sqlite-plugin-not-functioning-with-android-studio/33894275#33894275

Comment: @Dhruv Thank You, but I want to use the Plugin, because it gets updated, extended and of course bug fixed. When I just use the Script without the Plugin, then I don't have this advantage!

Answer (score 0):

From some digging in the Cordova library i found that the plugins loading order is according the config.xml file declaration.

In my case i wrote some custom plugins and didn't declared them in config.xml file. So i guess they was added in the build process to final config.xml file that you find in: `"platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml"`.

I tried to remove the plugin i wanted to init later and add install it again, and it worked.

So for the npm distributed plugins put them in wanted order in config.xml file and for your plugins install them in specific order you want.